# Xcode 12.3 constantly crashes after update

Tags: xcode, macos

I wanted to update Xcode to 12.3, but there wasn't enough space for that on my MacBook, so I downloaded Xcode 12.3 from [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/), and unarchived the `.xip` file on an external SSD. After that, I moved Xcode back to the laptop, and now when I want to launch Xcode (so when I launch the app, not a particular project!) it crashes with the following log:

```
Process:               Xcode [616]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               12.3 (17715)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-17715000000000000~8 (12C33)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [616]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2020-12-18 14:22:40.576 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 11.1 (20C69)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.1 (18P3030)
Anonymous UUID:        A6A1D2D4-69BA-5197-5F6F-C0FB4D60ADEB


Time Awake Since Boot: 91 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 12C33
ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-17718/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTExtendedPlatformInfo.m:110
Details:  (extensionPoint) should not be nil.
Object:   <DVTExtendedPlatformInfo>
Method:   +extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7faa6100a380>{number = 1, name = main}
Open FDs: 6/256
Hints:   
 
Backtrace:
  0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   __75+[DVTExtendedPlatformInfo extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:]_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  4   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  5   _dispatch_once_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   +[DVTExtendedPlatformInfo extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
  7   -[DVTPlatform(DVTExtendedPlatformInfo) dvt_extendedInfoOrError:] (in DVTFoundation)
  8   +[DVTPlatform validatePlatformDataReturningError:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9   IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
 10   -[IDEApplicationController applicationWillFinishLaunching:] (in IDEKit)
 11   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
 12   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
 13   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 14   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
 15   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
 16   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions_MRR) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
 17   -[NSApplication finishLaunching] (in AppKit)
 18   -[DVTApplication finishLaunching] (in DVTKit)
 19   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 20   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 21   start (in libdyld.dylib)
 
abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
((extensionPoint)) != nil
```

I've tried everything I could find online:

- restart Mac (in safe mode)
- update macOS to Big Sur 11.1
- reinstall Xcode Command Line Tools
- clear derived data
- clear all Xcode associated files (excepting the app itself) using AppCleaner

Do you have any idea on how I can fix this?

By the way, isn't it strange that the file that gives `ASSERTION FAILURE` doesn't even exist on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow managed to free up around 40 GB on my MacBook, so I was able to download Xcode from App Store. And it seems like this was a "cleaner" install, stopping Xcode from crashing.